# Android findViewById() returns null

Tags: java, android

I know that there are a lot of questions simmilar to mine, but none of them gave me an answer.

I have a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and when in Activity's onCreate happens the following:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layoutMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
```

linearLayout and scrollView both contain Views I need but layoutMain is null. How can that happen and how do I get `findViewById(R.id.layout_main)`?

Comment: "I have a layout" -- is this `R.layout.activity_main`? If yes, do you have other versions of `activity_main.xml` in other resource sets (e.g., `res/layout-land/`)? What IDE are you using, if any?

Comment: Maybe your view is not being initialized because it is missing the layout_width, and layout_height parameters in the xml

Comment: @CommonsWare I use android studio, layout is activity_main.xml.

Comment: @DanielMendel it does have layout_width and layout_height, I didn't copy it in order not to make the question look too messy.

Comment: @CommonsWare is correct do you have different versions of activity_main.xml in different layout folders

Comment: Make sure the R class you are using is the generated for your application and not the one that belongs to android

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio wait for the gradle to finish building the project, this will probably solve the problem. Also try restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You have no layout_height. Set it on match_patent.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml layout is missing important attributes. Provide `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` for views. See following xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**

As you said in comments that width/height attributes are present in actual code. Then I suggest **Delete sub directories of build folder** under your project's module and rebuild project